# Fit an image inside an image

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, background

Using CSS, is there a way to fit this image:
[image]
inside this phone image (only a phone border):[image]

setting it as a background image will take up a **full rectangle** that doesn't fit the border of the phone but more.

this is how the code looks like

```
                <div class="leftPhone">
                     <img class="LRPhone" src="images/leftphone.svg" alt="">
                </div>
```

Comment: Use css border radius on the div to match radius of phone corners. Or make phone into a full reactangle with transparent middle

Comment: use background-size:contain; add no-repeat and use radius if you wish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would help a lot to trim off the excess whitespace around the phone image so you don't need to monkey around with the positioning.  Also, the size/aspect ratio of the picture and phone frame is not the same so you'll need to play around with the background size/position to get it the way you want.   But all you really need to do is set the border-radius to match the phone image.

```css
.leftPhone {
  background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/6XUJf.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 150px 200px;
  background-position: -30px -20px;
  width: 88px;
  height: 175px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.leftPhone img {
  position: absolute;
  left: -48px;
  top: -5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="leftPhone">
  <img class="LRPhone" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/sYhYo.png" alt="">
</div>
```